# How to plot a multi-histogram density (or raw count) plot from a matrix having rows which are unequal in length?

Tags: r

I have 17 vectors containing counts, the length of these vectors range from 2000 to 7000 in length.
I searched the internet for how to plot multi-histograms and I read in some places that it's possible to do it by forming a matrix, so I merged the vectors using rbind.
I saw methods incorporating ggplot like:
 ggplot(df, aes(x=count,group=year,fill=as.factor(year)))

But, I think that these examples had equal length, so I'm wondering if it is possible to plot multiple vectors on the same grid in terms of density despite them each having different lengths? And whether I can arbitrarily approximate the x-axis (counts) and y-axis (density)?

Comment: Could you give some sample data?

Comment: rps_101_150:    1,    0,    0,    4,    9  

rps_151_200:    3,    4,    9,    7,    8  

rps_201_250:    4,    6,   14,    7,    6  

rps_251_300:   16,   18,    8,    9,  14  

rps_301_350:   11,   15,    7,    9,    7    

But the lengths of these vectors are unequal i.e. 6598, 6540, 6965, 6964, 6218.  

edit: I'm terrible at formatting my comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, columns for shorter vectors have NA's in missing rows, following would be one way to do it.

```
p1 <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = year1)) + geom_histogram()
p1 <- p1 + geom_histogram(aes(x = year2), col = "red", na.rm=TRUE)
...
p1
```

Naturally, take care to specify appropriate bin widths and x-axis range. Admit this isn't very elegant.

Comment: It's my fault for using that example as it bears no relevance to my data. 
I want to understand the terms that comprise the ggplot function.
My vectors are named rps_101-150, rps_151-200 etc right up to 1000.

With this in mind what does p1 refer to? 
What does data refer to?
And is x each individual vector?

Comment: `x` is a column name in data frame, it could be rps_101-150, for which you want to plot a histogram. 
`p1` is the ggplot object.  To actually see the plot, you have to type just `p1` at the end.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it won't work because when I try to create a data frame from all of my ranges it states:

Error in data.frame:  arguments imply differing number of rows:

It seems I can only combine the vectors using rbind or cbind. Does it have to be a data frame or can it be a matrix?

Comment: It must be a data frame. From the question you asked, you imply you have a data frame... You should read the documentation in ggplot.

Also, you should read the guide lines for asking questions in stackoverflow. If I've answered your question you should accept it. Further questions should be posted as new ones.

Comment: By the way, I can't see much point in having 17 histograms in one plot! You may not even some of them. Try either density plots or separate histograms.

Comment: Thank you for your help Disco, I went with separate histograms.
I will experiment with the ggplot with some more straightforward data.

Comment: Hey Mr, consider hitting the tick mark next my answer if it help solve the question you asked. I am letting you know since you are seems new to here.